# Is there a way to instantiate a sub-class and not inherit a specific property?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, properties

Let's assume the code below:

```
class Animal{
  constructor(name){
    this.name=name;
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
  constructor(lastname){
    super();
    this.lastname=lastname;
  }
}

var animal = new Animal('jim');
var rudy = new Dog('rudy');
```

Other than `delete rudy.name` after the subclass has instantiated is there another way of instantiate the subclass directly without the name property from the parent class?

Comment: that would violate oop principles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite it with a non-string value, in particular `undefined`, which is similar to a not existing property:

```
class Dog extends Animal{
  constructor(lastname){
    super(undefined);
    this.lastname=lastname;
  }
}
```

But really, if your class doesn't have all the properties that the "parent" class has, it should not be a subclass at all - it would violate the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).